# Is it possible to compare time series method with non-time series method?

Tags: time-series

Is it make sense that time series method to be compared with non-time series method ? and if it is possible could somebody tell me which non-times series method can I apply to make comparison between time series method and others for make a decision.

Comment: We'd really need to know more about what you're doing in order to answer the second part of your question well.

Comment: @jbowman. I am doing time series prediction. I have used ARIMA, MA, ES, and random walk. I would like to know can i compare these time series based model to non-time series model like multiple linear regression ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  A non-time series method that I have used (as a "hack") to model time series is a generalized additive model (GAM) with a nonparametrically-smoothed time effect.  For example, using the `mgcv` package in `R`, if `y` is the response variable and `t` is time, you could run something like `model = gam(y~s(t))`.

This is not a standard time series model, probably due to the fact that it makes no explicit accommodation for autocorrelation over time.  That is, the model assumes that the observations are i.i.d.

Comment: It is relatively easy to make that model account for autocorrelation. One option is to use `gamm()` and employ the `correlation` argument of the `lme()` function (of package **nlme**. Another is to follow the example in `?magic` (also in **mgcv**) whereby you make some guesses as to the complexities of the smooths, fit model, estimate the appropriate covariance matrix and use it to update the model fit.